# SwiftUI: @GestureState with @State not working as intended (MRE included)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## TL;DR

There's a minimum working example (with a solution!) at the end of this post. After toggling the menu sheet I implemented, try dismissing it with a swipe left gesture. You'll be able to see an animation glitch. I'd like to know what is causing this issue, and why the solution fixes it. Please keep reading if you would like to take a look at my observations.

---

## Observations

I'm trying to implement a `MenuSheet`, which can be dismissed with a single swipe left gesture. I created `@Binding var isOpen: Bool` and `@GestureState var translation: CGFloat`, so if `translation` becomes less than zero at the time the gesture *completes* (which implies swipe left), `isOpen` is changed to `false`.

I also know that when the gesture *completes*, the `@GestureState` resets its property back to its initial state, which is zero.

Putting all these together, there are two state changes that should happen when the swipe left gesture completes:

- `translation := 0`
- `isOpen := false`

I assumed the two state changes occur at the same time before the view rerenders. However, my observation was that **1)** the `translation` is first set to `0` and the view rerenders, **2)** which is followed by `isOpen` being set to `false` with a second view rerender.

This causes an inconsistency because right before **2)**, the two states instantaneously become `translation == 0 && isOpen == true` and it renders the view as if the menu sheet is open, even though I just finished swipe left gesture to dismiss the sheet. This leads to a weird animation glitch.

Strangely, I could solve this issue by simply wrapping `isOpen` in an `@ObservableObject`. The solution is attached below, too.

I'd like to know what is causing this issue and why the solution fixes it. Specifically, the following are some questions that might be related:

- How does SwiftUI handle view rerender when two or more states are changed almost simultaneously?
- Do `@State` and `@ObservedObject` behave differently when it comes to determining when to refresh the view? How?

Thank you!

---

## Code

**This example code reproduces the issue only in Preview mode. To run it in the simulator, please refer to Update section below.**

Tested in Swift Playground 4, iPadOS 15.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MenuSheet<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let maxWidth: CGFloat = 290
    
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
            state = value.translation.width
        }
        .onEnded { value in
            self.isOpen = value.translation.width >= 0
        }
    }
    
    private var offset: CGFloat {
        isOpen ? 0 : maxWidth
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("redrawing body with isOpen:\(self.isOpen), translation: \(self.translation)")
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ZStack {
                Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                self.content()
            }
            .frame(width: maxWidth, height: reader.size.height)
            .offset(x: min(-self.offset + self.translation, 0))
            .animation(.default, value: isOpen)
        }
        .highPriorityGesture(
            dragGesture
        )
    }
}

/// A simple wrapper that is used to preview `MenuSheet`.
struct MenuSheetWrapper: View {
    @State var isOpen = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                isOpen.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Tap this button to toggle!")
            }
            
            MenuSheet(isOpen: $isOpen) {
                Text("Swipe left to dismiss.")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MenuSheetWrapper_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuSheetWrapper()
    }
}
```

## Solution

Replace `MenuSheetWrapper` with the following code.

```swift
/// A simple wrapper that is used to preview `MenuSheet`.
struct MenuSheetWrapper: View {
    class AppState: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isOpen = false
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var appState = AppState()
//    @State var isOpen = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                appState.isOpen.toggle()
//                isOpen = !isOpen
            } label: {
                Text("Tap this button to toggle!")
            }
            
            MenuSheet(isOpen: $appState.isOpen) {
                Text("Swipe left to dismiss.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Update

To reproduce the issue in the simulator, replace your @main `App` with the following code snippet.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    @State private var isOpen = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                Button {
                    isOpen.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Tap this button to toggle!")
                }
                MenuSheet(isOpen: $isOpen) {
                    Text("Swipe left to dismiss.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see any glitches here... the only I'd change probably is to `value: offset` instead.

Comment: Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5, just in case

Comment: @Asperi Well, things are getting weird.. I could confirm that the example code reproduces the glitch only when you launch the app in preview mode. In my full project however, it also occurs in the simulator. Any idea what's making the difference? I'll try to come up with another example in the meanwhile.

Comment: Simulator is some kind of device preview, but Preview is a simulator's preview. IMO and by my experience Preview is restricted variant of simulator targeted basically for "static UI preview", so it is better to avoid testing some complex dynamic behavior with it. It's better to use Simulator and if there are doubts - real device.

Comment: @Asperi I get your point. Can you try the code snippet in the **Update** section? It should reproduce the issue in the simulator. Please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I even will not. It is wrong approach to do that in scene at that level. Scene should contain one root view (similarly as NS/UIWindow rootView/viewController) - everything else should be managed within that root view.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the root cause of this issue. Thanks! One last question though: doesn't `ZStack` also conform to `View`? What's the point of wrapping it in another root `View`?